# Using DataGridView events to save data back on the database

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, generic-list

I have a `DataGridView` in a form and I'm populating the grid using a `List<Object>`.

```
bindingSource.DataSource = List;       
_View.GridData = bindingSource; //GridData is a property in the UI which encapsulates grid's datasource property.
```

Once the grid fully populated I want to fire an event which then save the data in the grid back on the database.

```
OnSaveGridData (sender, e);
```

BUT individual changes made to the grid data (like changing the value in a cell) should not fire this event.

How can I do this?

Comment: Pls not I cannot use `rowAdded` as it fires every time a row is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
void dataGridView_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("datasourcechanged");
    }
```